# Accessing a base model's field in parent class without abstraction

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to create unicode and I want to get the field from the inherit table. Like this:

```
 class EnvelopeBase(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50
        )
    ...........        

class Envelope(EnvelopeBase):
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        EnvelopeCategory, 
        blank=True, null=True
        )

    ........

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{0}: {1}".format(self.category, self.name)
```

Notice that, I'm creating unicode in the Envelope model and I'm trying to get the "self.name" which is from EnvelopeBase model. I didn't get error but the output is null. How to access the name field in the ENvelopeBase model to Envelope model?

**UPDATE:**

What I'm trying to do is display the category and envelope name like this for example:

Let say I have category = 'Savings' and envelope = 'maintenance'

The output must be (from the unicode implementation):

```
 def __unicode__(self):
    //the self.name here return null
    return "{0}: {1}".format(self.category, self.name)

 Output: "Savings: maintenance"
```

But my problem is only ****savings (category)**** is shown **no maintenance (envelope)**. The self.name is from EnvelopeBase model which is I'm trying to access to Envelope model

Comment: Could you show a simplified code snippet of how you're using these models to get the unexpected output?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm looking for something like this:

    `envelope = Envelope(name='Sam', category=some_category_instance);
    envelope.save();
    print(envelope);
    print(envelope.__unicode__())`

What would something like that output given your current models?

Comment: @ZebDeOs I'm not saving it. I'm trying to display them.

Comment: I think @ZebDeOs means where are you querying the db to display the data?

Comment: yeah in the modelform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using inheritance in django models two tables are created for parent and child models.
A foreign key column is added to the child model with the name Parent_ptr_id that is meant to refer to a corresponding row in the parent table.

Let's say we have two models(Parent and Child):

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    parent_field = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.parent_field

class Child(Parent):
    child_field = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.parent_field + ': ' + self.child_field
```

When you create an instance of the child model you should specify the parent_field too.

```
child = Child(child_field='a', parent_field='b')
```

If you don't specify the parent_field, the new parent row inserted will have parent_field set to null. This might have happened to your data.

Also, when you create an instance of the child model you can specify an existing parent_ptr_id.

```
child = Child(child_field='c', parent_field='d', parent_ptr_id=1)
```

This causes the parent_field of the existing parent to be updated to the new value. The tricky part is that if you don't specify the parent_field here the parent_field in the already existing parent row will be updated to null. This might have happened to your data too.

Apart from that, your existing code should work. (self.envelopebase.name is not needed as far as I know)

Comment: Very cool, I actually didn't know about this type of relation until she mentioned that she didn't want abstraction. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

You want to make your base model abstract https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

```
class EnvelopeBase(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50
    )

    ...........

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Envelope(EnvelopeBase):
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        EnvelopeCategory, 
        blank=True, null=True
    )

    ........

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{0}: {1}".format(self.category, self.name)
```

---

The other way is mult-table inheritance https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance

Basically, you don't have to do anything. Django automatically creates a one-to-one relation between the two. All of the fields in the base class will be available in the parent class but the data will exist in a different table.

```
class EnvelopeBase(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50
    )

    ...........


class Envelope(EnvelopeBase):
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        EnvelopeCategory, 
        blank=True, null=True
    )

    ........

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{0}: {1}".format(self.category, self.envelopebase.name)
```

Comment: Thanks, but don't use abstract. That EnvelopeBase model also handle data in the database

Comment: You should really be using foreign keys if both persist in the database and are related.

Comment: That codes is from my employer. I'm updating it because he wants to show both category and envelope in the selected option

Comment: I don't understand how they can be related like this, sorry. Maybe someone else can help...

Comment: Thanks, maybe I can find solution later :/

Comment: @catherine Should be pretty easy. I updated my answer. Before you asked, I didn't know about this feature :P

Comment: Yeah, it works now :) Thank you. I try self.envelopebase_ptr_id but no luck